# Retrieving uploaded files from server hard disk

Tags: jsp, download

(I am using netbeans 6.8,  running a Java Web Application,  Glassfish server)
Assume i am storing the uploaded files in C:\temp folder...
and my Netbeans project path is C:\NetBeans\WebApplication3...
Is there any way i can **stream** or make the files in C:\temp folder available for **download**.....
(without storing it in a database)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to store the file in C:\ drive since it will violate the security feature of java, hence you to save the file in a temporary folder.

Then you can use **properties file** or use **servletContext.getRealPath()** to access the file.

Comment: Storing the files in C:\temp is not a problem (it works!!)...But i dont know how to stream or make it available for download...What do you mean by temporary folder?? is it \WebApplication3\build\web folder??

Comment: What i was looking for was a way to download a file on the server (dynamic)... I got the solution from (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html)

Comment: Why you have to upload it in C/temp because any user can upload the virus effected file.

Comment: It doesnt matter if i upload in c:\temp or c:\new folder or d:\.... i only wanted to know **how to retrieve that**...because <a href="filename.extension"></a> does not work for files which are added(uploaded) after the build and run process... glassfish will throw resource not available error..